# Using iterator on a ArraySet

Tags: java, iterator

I have a arrayset, that want the iterator to point to the beginning of the set. Not sure how to implement this, below is what I have so far.

```
public ArraySet() {
    // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
    collection = new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    capacity = 0;
}

/**
 * Returns an iterator for this set of objects.
 * @pre true
 * @post Set is not changed
 * @return An iterator for the set of objects that points to   the                 beginning
 *         of the set.
 */

public SetIterator iterator() {

   ArraySet testArraySet = new ArraySet();
   SetIterator arraySetIterator = testArraySet.iterator();
   while (arraySetIterator.hasNext())
   {
    Object element = arraySetIterator.next();          
    return element;     
   }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That is not how an `iterator` works (you've implemented `next` in your `iterator()` method). Also, it's an empty `Set` you are iterating. Finally, you could just `return testArraySet.iterator();` (but as I mentioned, it's empty).

Comment: You're calling `ArraySet.iterator()` from inside `ArraySet.iterator()`.  This is not useful.  You need to create a new class that actually implements the `SetIterator` interface, though it can be an inner class of `ArraySet`.

Comment: So would have a private class Set Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are going for is to have `ArraySet` implement the `Set<E>` interface. This will force you to implement various methods, including the `iterator()` method. You will also have to create your own class that implements `Iterator<E>`. This is what will be returned by the `ArraySet.iterator()` method.

To make things a little more concrete below is a little code snippet of the structure I described.

```
public class ArraySet<E> implements Set<E>{

    /*
    requrired methods here
    */
    Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new MyIterator<E>(this);
    }

    private class MyIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{
        /*
        requrired methods here
        */
    }
}
```

Follow these links for more info on Java [Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [Iterators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). If this still confuses you, I suggest looking into [how other iterators are used first](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm).